# SSIS SharePoint List Source - Loaded 0 Records

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, bids

I created a SSIS package in BIDS that pulls data from a sharepoint list and inserts it into a **SQL Server** database using OLE DB Destination.  This SSIS package works perfectly, and data is being populated.  I then needed to pull data from a different SharePoint list on the same site.

I am using the exact same credentials, same read/write access, and almost identical SSIS packages.  However, on this new SSIS package, there are 0 records being loaded.

There are no errors or warnings in the execution results page.  To ensure there is not some setting I missed, I copied the data flow task from the working SSIS package into the SSIS package that is not loading any records.

The data flow task that I just copied pulls information from its SharePoint List as expected, so I know there is not some setting that I am missing.

Any thoughts about why this is happening?  Google hasn't been much help on this and I am stumped.

The execution results page says:

```
[SharePoint List Source] Information: Loaded 0 records from list 'LISTNAME' at 'SITEURL'. Elapsed time is 131ms
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of the view that you put in the SharePoint List Source (SLS) Component Properties.  The SLS will only pull items that are visible in the specified view. For example if you create a new calendar and add 10 items in the next month, they will not show up in the default view "calendar".  But if you change the view (in SharePoint or SSIS) to "All Events", you will see your 10 items show up in your browser and also as rows in the SSIS package.

Answer (score 0):

Use OData source of a tool on MSSQL 2014/16, which successfully load whole list and data as well.